# Using http request on Yahoo Map Service C#

Tags: c#, .net, yahoo-maps

I'm currently using yahoo map service to display a static image of a location with the latitude and longitude that I suppiled, and this work fine.

But I was just wondering if it possible to send an url request to the service that will return an image
with multiple markers on the image? (ie. more than one locations marked).

If anyone know how to do this, please help!

Thank you very much!

ps. I am developing my application for windows mobile using .NET CF 3.5 with windows mobile 6 professional as a target platform.

Comment: What is the http parameter you are using to "Mark" the location?

Answer (score 0):

[HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) ought to be able to provide you with this capability

Comment: Ah thank but that's not exactly the problem I have, I can use HttpWebRequest class to get an image of yahoo map service just fine 

But the problem is I can only seem to get just 1 location marked on my map image. 

I'd like to know if it's possible to suppile the web service with multiple latitude and longitude in the same query and get back an image that have multiple location marked on the map.

Cheer!